# HTML form element not showing in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm confused on how to make an HTML form element show up on my form view in my rails app.  I'm using the HTML template for Thomas Bradley's [signature pad](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/), with the "draw only" option.

Here's my form view:

```
    <%= form_for(@cms849) do |f| %>
  <% if @cms849.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@cms849.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this cms849 from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @cms849.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
      </div>
      <form method="post" action":signature" class="sigPad">
  <p class="drawItDesc">Draw your signature</p>
  <ul class="sigNav">
    <li class="drawIt"><a href="#draw-it">Draw It</a></li>
    <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sig sigWrapper">
    <canvas class="pad" width="198" height="55"></canvas>
    <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">I accept the terms of this agreement.</button>
</form> 
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :signer_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :signer_name %>
  </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
    <%= render partial: "partials/signatureform" %>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Just to check my work I put the form in it's own partial, which works, but won't render in place of the form inserted from HTML.

I'm sure this is a simple HTML/Ruby issue but I can't seem to track it down on my own.  I tried using raw as well with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to nest a `form` inside `form_for`, which will output it's own `form` element. That's not valid HTML.

No idea if this will work, but can you combine the `class` you need for the plugin to work with the `form_for`?

```
<%= form_for(@cms849, html: { class: 'sigPad' }) do |f| %>
  <% if @cms849.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@cms849.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this cms849 from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @cms849.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <p class="drawItDesc">Draw your signature</p>
  <ul class="sigNav">
    <li class="drawIt"><a href="#draw-it">Draw It</a></li>
    <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sig sigWrapper">
    <canvas class="pad" width="198" height="55"></canvas>
    <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :signer_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :signer_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'I accept the terms of this agreement.' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I applied your proposed solution and it seems to work that way, but it removes the f.label and doesn't load on first load of the page.  On second page the sigPad form loads but the f.label is still missing.  Any ideas?